# Making "warning: array 'foo' assumed to have one element" an error

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, gcc-warning

I accidentally declared an array without a length by writing `enum foo bar[];`, and gcc gave me the warning "`array 'bar' assumed to have one element`".

Is there any way to make gcc turn this into an error, instead of just warning me and assuming I meant `enum foo bar[1]`? I can't think of any circumstances under which I'd purposely leave out an array's length.

Comment: Per 6.9.2, the tentative definition `enum foo bar[];` becomes `enum foo bar[] = {0};` if there is no external definition in the translation unit. So the compiler goes beyond its duty to warn about it, be thankful for that. Unfortunately, since it warns about that by default, I think you can only turn it into an error by making all warnings errors.

Comment: @DanielFischer Till now,I have had it drilled into my head that in C it's mandatory to mention the size of the array during declaration unless you are initializing it there.How correct am I?Or things have changed after C99 or C11?Shall I conclude something like `int arr[];` mean array `arr` is assumed to have size `1` and the only element is initialized to `0`?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture This is for file scope things. For those, tentative definitions turn into real definitions if there is no external definition in the translation unit, and for arrays declared without dimension, that results in one-element arrays. For block scope declarations, the size is mandatory, either explicitly between the brackets, or implicitly from the initialiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

You can use -Werror to turn all warnings into errors. I couldn't find an option to turn only that one into an error.

Comment: Might as well turn on -Wall, as well, to give you as many warnings to turn into errors as possible.  It's almost never you don't want to fix everything in -Wall